# trying to read live rss, but its returning same xml

Tags: php, curl, simplexml

I am trying to read xml file from "http://synd.cricbuzz.com/score-gadget/gadget-scores-feed.xml" I understand its caching issue so i have added no-cache but stil its returning same file :(

```
<?php 
    header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
    header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
    header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
    header("Pragma: no-cache"); Header('Pragma: no-cache');

    $url = "http://synd.cricbuzz.com/score-gadget/gadget-scores-feed.xml";

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec ($curl);
    curl_close ($curl);
    print $result;
    $fp = fopen('score.xml', 'w');
    if($fp)
        fwrite($fp,  $result);  
    else
    echo "Error !";

    $url = "score.xml";
    $xml = simplexml_load_file($url);

    var_dump($xml);
 ?>
```

Comment: Where is the caching occurring ? calling your PHP or calling the remote XML ?

Comment: calling remote xml...when i try to output CURL output it returns the same (old) xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the following options to prevent caching :

```
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1); 
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, 1);
```

[Docs on curl_setopt here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)